# Connect Azure Data Catalog REST API using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

i want to connect to Azure Data Catalog RestAPI using power shell script and below is my script which failed to run.

#### Get an Access Token with ADAL

```
$authContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext ("{0}" -f $login)

$authenticationResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($ResourceId, $ClientId, $redirectUri, $PromptBehavior);

($token = $authenticationResult.AccessToken) | Out-File $accessToken

$authContext.AcquireToken($ResourceId, $ClientId, $redirectUri, $PromptBehavior)


$headers = @{ 

    "Authorization" = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token);

}

$url = "https://api.azuredatacatalog.com/catalogs/DefaultCatalog/search/search?searchTerms=name:=Orders&count=10&api-version=2016-03-30"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $headers
```

#### I am getting below error message

> Invoke-RestMethod : 
>   401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>   Server Error
>
> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>     You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
>
> At line:1 char:13
>   + $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $headers
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Please help me in resolving the issue

Comment: Are you using a Service Principal, Application, or an AD user to connect?

Comment: Below are the details used to connect.                                                                     # Output Token and Response from AAD Graph API
                                                                                                  
$accessToken = ".\Token.txt"

$output = ".\Output.json"

# Application and Tenant Configuration

$clientId = "****.****.****.****.****"

$resourceId = "https://api.azuredatacatalog.com"

$redirectUri = New-Object system.uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf")

$login = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to grant your application access to the Azure Data Catalog via Azure AD.

[image]

Do note that this may require Administrator Approval to complete.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. We have permissions to access azure data catalog and still we face the same issue.